# Куда делась вся память?

Tags: linux, debian, память

Debian 9

```
 # free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64063       52605        9638         120        1819       10790
Swap:          7624         576        7048
```

При этом:

```
 # ps aux | awk '{print $2, $4, $11}' | sort -k2rn | head -n 20
172643 10.8 /usr/sbin/mysqld
588 0.1 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
100 0.0 [watchdog/15]
10 0.0 [migration/0]
1 0.0 /sbin/init
```

Больше  всего ест mysql, то там всего около 10гб, никаких больше процессов не вижу.
У mysql tmpdir сейчас на диске, но куда-то утекло почти 40гб памяти

```
# mount|grep tmpfs
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=32789168k,nr_inodes=8197292,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=6560128k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6560124k,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=6560124k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

И топ:

```
top - 23:21:59 up 242 days,  4:23,  2 users,  load average: 2.32, 2.26, 2.26
Tasks: 422 total,   1 running, 421 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.8 us,  1.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 93.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 65601252 total,  9658672 free, 53966096 used,  1976484 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  7807996 total,  7217448 free,   590548 used. 10949900 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
172643 mysql     20   0 25.487g 6.860g  17308 S 156.8 11.0 265:40.61 mysqld
   588 root      20   0  168980  87092  86892 S   0.0  0.1  33:08.04 systemd-journal
175380 root      20   0  449268  47440  39816 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.53 php-fpm7.1
 88856 root       0 -20   27556  10564   3540 S   0.0  0.0   1:19.55 atop
175408 trof      20   0  449268   9236   1612 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 php-fpm7.1
175410 trof      20   0  449268   9236   1612 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 php-fpm7.1
175404 trof      20   0  449268   9232   1608 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 php-fpm7.1
175405 trof      20   0  449268   9232   1608 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175406 trof      20   0  449268   9232   1608 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.06 php-fpm7.1
175407 trof      20   0  449268   9232   1608 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 php-fpm7.1
175409 trof      20   0  449268   9232   1608 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175401 trof      20   0  449268   9228   1604 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175402 trof      20   0  449268   9228   1604 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175403 trof      20   0  449268   9228   1604 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175400 trof      20   0  449268   9224   1600 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175397 trof      20   0  449268   9220   1600 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175398 trof      20   0  449268   9220   1600 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175399 trof      20   0  449268   9220   1600 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175394 trof      20   0  449268   9216   1596 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175388 trof      20   0  449268   9208   1588 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175389 trof      20   0  449268   9208   1588 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
175384 trof      20   0  449268   9204   1584 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.1
178616 root      20   0   97592   7364   5984 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.19 sshd
175978 root      20   0   97332   7060   6064 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.04 sshd



tmpfs           6.3G  658M  5.7G  11% /run
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Содержимое meminfo:

```
MemTotal:       65601252 kB
MemFree:         8239460 kB
MemAvailable:    9895136 kB
Buffers:         1061512 kB
Cached:          1184596 kB
SwapCached:         6556 kB
Active:          8732688 kB
Inactive:         936924 kB
Active(anon):    7508928 kB
Inactive(anon):    41896 kB
Active(file):    1223760 kB
Inactive(file):   895028 kB
Unevictable:       10728 kB
Mlocked:           10728 kB
SwapTotal:       7807996 kB
SwapFree:        7218032 kB
Dirty:               128 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       7428028 kB
Mapped:           117408 kB
Shmem:            123728 kB
Slab:            1990788 kB
SReclaimable:     100832 kB
SUnreclaim:      1889956 kB
KernelStack:       12208 kB
PageTables:        35620 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    40608620 kB
Committed_AS:   22557644 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     63488 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:    27339288 kB
DirectMap2M:    39421952 kB
DirectMap1G:     2097152 kB
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90217/discussion-on-question-by-vitroot----).